# Collect XML, or CSV data from links, into website in form of tables or similar

Tags: html, xml, web-scraping, tabular

I want to collect data from link below into website in form of table of some sort... Can someone give me a clue, as I am low on programming knowledge. I know something, can learn, but I'm too old and low basic programming knowledge for doing it. So if anyone can at least point me what to search, I would try to figure it out. It can also be from CSV format also generated in link:

[Link of XML data](http://server.fseconomy.net/data?userkey=2TBUVXWKWA&format=xml&query=flightlogs&search=id&readaccesskey=VWLKMB55L8&fromid=2178373)

[Link of my website, id id this without any knowledge, I'm selfstudy, but have no patience like before](http://aircroatiava.com/vam/index.php?lang=hr)

[Link of CSV data](http://server.fseconomy.net/data?userkey=2TBUVXWKWA&format=csv&query=flightlogs&search=id&readaccesskey=VWLKMB55L8&fromid=2178373)

Answer (score 0):

To accomplish what you intend to do, you will need to be able to read the content from the urls that you have listed. You have indicated that you will need support for both XML and CSV.

Here is how you would read XML content from a url using jQuery:

```
$(function() {
    $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: "http://server.fseconomy.net/data?userkey=2TBUVXWKWA&format=xml&query=flightlogs&search=id&readaccesskey=VWLKMB55L8&fromid=2178373",
        dataType: "xml",
        success: function(data) {
            ...do something with your data...
        },
        error: function(xhr, status, error) {
        }
    });
});
```

Reading content from a url with CSV content is a little bit trickier since there is no native type to handle such content. That being said, there are packages available to help handle the conversion of CSV content. Since links become unavailable after some time, I urge you to search for these packages using Google. There are plenty to choose from.

Comment: I will play myself with the one you posted...I wanna put some data from that XML, not all in table. So i have only pilot, plane, earnings etc. So i want to extract those data, all in separate column, with rows as stated...hm...i will play with this. Will post something if i stuck after a while ;) thank you

Comment: Can someone actually put me all webpage in html, or on private, i will pay him for beer or something. I really dont have a clue how to implement this into my webpage. I did tr all night and im all brainwashed hehe...I need a liitle explanations on everything. You guys sing this coding like poems, for me its all kind of messed up...sorry. So pm me, or something, we can negotitate something, but i need this to be done somehow. thank you